# How can I change the camera matrix(just different focal length) without changing the projection of a model's 3D pose on an image plane?

Tags: math, 3d, camera, computer-vision

I have a 3d pose that with a specific camera matrix projects well on 2D image plane. However the camera matrix is not the real one(the transformation matrix is found from a CNN network). I want to propagate to the real Camera Matrix (with only focal length different), how the real rotation and translation will be , given that the final 3d pose should project on the same points in 2d plane?

I was thinking this equation

`[R|t]_real = K_real^{-1}*K_temp*[R|t]_temp`

where [R|t]_real and K_real are the real transformation matrix and camera matrix, while the K_temp, [R|t]_temp are the temporary one that project well on 2D image plane.

From the above equation, it seems that translation X, Y will change while the Z will stay constant.

Comment: the "focal length" is a scale factor. you have a difference in scale and you want to move it into the model instead of the projection. that means you need to apply it to either the x and y coordinates, or the z coordinate, of your model (in camera space).

Comment: yes but the image does not change and the projection of the model in 2d plane should be the same. In adition to this, model is remaining the same so that's why only x and y coordinates are changing. Am i wrong in this proof?

Comment: can't debug this without something that's more tangible than words.

Comment: I have a CNN netwrok that outputs a transformation matrix that given a specific camera matrix , a model can be projected well on the 2d image plane. I want to keep constant the projection of the model and change the camera matrix (with the real camera matrix) and get the real transformation matrix. The calculations i reffered to are found from projection equation in pinhole model 
[Q,1]^T ~ K * [R|t] * [P, 1]^T, where Q are the (u,v) projections on 2d plane, K the camera matrix, [R|t] the transformation matrix, P the 3d model expressed in model coordinate system.

Comment: I didn't mean more words. I meant a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The general pinhole camera projection equation for a 3D point `X` and its image `x` is:

```
x = s * K * [R|t] * X
```

With a given camera pose `[R|t]`, and a given camera matrix `K`, you have only one degree of freedom left: the global scale of the scene `s`, which cannot be recovered from a monocular view.

So, choose your poison: if you want to change the camera matrix leaving the camera pose and the scene projection unchanged, your only option is to apply a scale `s'` to the camera matrix, and its reciprocal to the world scene:

```
x = s * (s' * K) * (X / s')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i dont want to leave camera pose unchanged. The unchanged are the projection points and the 3d model. Changing the focal length would change the camera pose [R|t]. This is why i proposed the equation
[R|t]' = K'^(-1)*K*[R|t]

Comment: Three general images of the same plane determine a calibration (intr. & extr, see e.g. Z. Zhang's paper for proof) with a general pinhole camera. So you cannot arbitrarily change K and Rt and be consistent with 3  or more views of the same plane. If K is just one focal length (no skew, principal point at the center of the image), then one image alone determines the calibration.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. So in that case where principal point is at the center and no skew, it is valid to change K and Rt leaving projections unchanged right?